# Picturebox locks out when form is minimized VB,NET

Tags: vb.net, locking, picturebox

I have a VB.NET GUI that is drawn inside a picturebox. Every time the form is minimized the control to the picturebox GUI is locked out. I do have good focus on the GUI in normal editing behavior. Also the windows controls keep working. It's just the picturebox. Anyone know what causes it?

This is some code I got off the net for doing a loop I thought but just streaming graphics,. Runcolor is part of my GUI.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.Show()
    Me.Focus()

    'G = Me.CreateGraphics
    'BB = New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)
    StartGameLoop()
End Sub

Private Sub StartGameLoop()
    Do While IsRunning = True
        Application.DoEvents()
        'Runcolor()
        DrawGraphics()
        '  TickCounter()
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub DrawGraphics()
    GUImain.GUIrunning()
End Sub
```

So every time the form is minimized or takes on the background the picture box running the GUI locks up, or actually this code running the GUI locks.

Regards,

Comment: When you say "GUI that is drawn inside a picturebox", what exactly do you mean? Are you somehow adding controls to `picturebox.Control`? Or again somehow adding controls to the picturebox `Graphics`?

Comment: I have one picturebox, and draw the entire GUI inside. So the picturebox is used for the drawing array for multiple controls.  At the moment I still have forms controls at the side of it. But not inside.

Comment: It also happens when its put to the background. Basically it now uses   Me.Show() and Me.Focus() when a mouse click is detected.

Comment: Can you show some pictures of what exactly you mean? And what's going wrong? I think a screenshot of your program could really help.

Comment: Ok, I will post some code I think is responsible. It runs on a loop i got from the internet. Where I took the loop out completely again except this.

Comment: Keith and Sastreen, Do you have the answer? Or maybe a hint? I don't think showing the sliders can be a lot of help. Can it be due to ownership? Still i'm clueless?